# Flutter/Dart http get request response is incomplete

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to perform a get request as follows:

```
  _makePlanGetRequest(int fileId) async {
    String url = 'http://192.168.1.17:8080/api/plan/download_plan/' + fileId.toString();

    print('URL: ' + url);

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    var response = await request.close();

    await for (var contents in response.transform(Utf8Decoder())) {
      print(contents);
    }
  }
```

However, when I use this function, response is incomplete. I checked the url in the browser and response is perfectly fine. How can I make the code work correctly? I would appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: It's probably not incomplete - it could just be that you overflow the console. It's rare to use HttpClient directly. Most people find `package:http` more convenient.

Comment: Exactly that's the reason. There is 1 kb limit on the console but the size of the response body points to completeness.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the content was limited on the console output due to a buffer limit I guess. However when I checked the size of the response body, It is exactly the size I expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dart package that provides some helper classes for http requests.

Github : https://github.com/Ephenodrom/Dart-Basic-Utils
Install it with:

```
dependencies:
  basic_utils: ^1.3.0
```

Usage

```dart
Map<String, String> headers = {
  "Some": "Header"
};
Map<String, String> queryParameters = {
  "Some": "Parameter"
};

String url = 'http://192.168.1.17:8080/api/plan/download_plan/' + fileId.toString();

// If the api returns json
Map<String, dynamic> dataAsJson = await HttpUtils.getForJson(url,
      headers: headers, queryParameters: queryParameters);
// if the api returns plain strings
String dataAsString = await HttpUtils.getForString(url,
      headers: headers, queryParameters: queryParameters);
// if the api returns something else like XML, EPP, KV, YAML 
Response fullResponse = await HttpUtils.getForFullResponse(url,
      headers: headers, queryParameters: queryParameters);
```

Additional information :

These are all methods from the HttpUtils class.

```dart
Future<Map<Response> getForFullResponse(String url,{Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getForJson(String url,{Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<String> getForString(String url,{Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<Response> postForFullResponse(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> postForJson(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<String> postForString(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Response> putForFullResponse(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> putForJson(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<String> putForString(String url, String body,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Response deleteForFullResponse(String url,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> deleteForJson(String url,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Future<String> deleteForString(String url,{Map<String, String> queryParameters,Map<String, String> headers});
Map<String, dynamic> getQueryParameterFromUrl(String url);
String addQueryParameterToUrl(String url, Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters);
```